# Including an attribute in SELECT without having to include it in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

I have a list of players who have hit Grand Slams this season, so far.

```
___________________________________________________
| Player Name | dateOfGrandSlam | distance | home |
---------------------------------------------------
|  Griffin    |    9-14-2013   |    413   | true |
|  Griffin    |    10-1-2013   |    371   | false|
|  Simpson    |    5-15-2013   |    413   | true |
|   Reid      |    7-1-2013    |    362   | true |
|   Reid      |    7-4-2013    |    363   | true |
|   Reid      |    9-28-2013   |    388   | true |
|  Peavis     |    8-14-2013   |    466   | false|
```

I want to get a list of players whose most recent grandslam was at home. If their most recent grandslam wasn't at home, I don't want them to show up on my list.
This means, I need to select the player and group by the player and select the max date from that group. In that list, I also have to include home/away information so I can pick out the ones that were not at home.

However I'm having a problem. Because in order to select the attribute `home`, I also need to include `home` in the `GROUP BY` clause.
For example:

```
SELECT playerName, MAX(date), distance, home 
FROM grandslams 
GROUP BY playerName, distance, home
```

The problem is that this returns a table with the most recent home and the most recent away grandslams.

---

```
| Player Name | dateOfGrandSlam | distance | home |
---------------------------------------------------
|  Griffin    |    9-14-2013   |    413   | true |
|  Griffin    |    10-1-2013   |    371   | false|
|  Simpson    |    5-15-2013   |    413   | true |
|   Reid      |    9-28-2013   |    388   | true |
```

This is not what I want - I want ONLY the most recent home grandslams IF there were no away grandslams more recently.

I want this result:

```
___________________________________________________
| Player Name | dateOfGrandSlam | distance | home |
---------------------------------------------------
|  Simpson    |    5-15-2013   |    413   | true |
|   Reid      |    9-28-2013   |    388   | true |
```

**Essentially** I need a way to perform the query that just gets me the most recent grandslam per player, tacks on the `home` attribute (without having to group by it so I don't get his most recent home and his most recent away) and then can be easily filtered in an outer query.

In other words, I need to get the result from

```
SELECT playerName, MAX(date), distance
FROM grandSlams
GROUP BY playerName, distance
```

and attach the `home` attribute to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the most recent grand slam for each player by using the `row_number()` function to enumerate the grand slams for each player, ordered by the date in descending order.  To choose the most recent, choose the one where the value is 1.  Then add the condition on the grand slam being from home:

```
select gs.*
from (select gs.*,
             row_number() over (partition by PlayerName
                                order by dateOfGrandSlam desc) as seqnum
      from GrandSlams gs
     ) gs
where seqnum = 1 and home = true;
```

Comment: Is there a more conventional way?

Comment: @Imray: that *is* the "conventional" way (it's standard ANSI SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Standard SQL is a "nice to have". Simplicity and performance are more important, IMO. Especially, since every RDBMS violates the standard anyway and also because the standard is rather silly in quite a few places (not here, mind you).

Answer (score 0):

You can first find all of the last home runs, then join them to the original table.

```
SELECT g.* from (SELECT playerName, MAX(date) date
FROM grandslams 
GROUP BY playerName) a
NATURAL JOIN grandslams g
WHERE g.home = true;
```

If you are not a fan of natural join (for ansi's sake) you can always use

```
JOIN grandslams g on g.playerName = a.playerName and g.date = a.date
```

instead of the natural join.
this would make the query ansi.

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down.

1)  Build a query that gets you the players whose last slam was at home. I.e., their most recent home slam was their most recent slam.

```
SELECT
  playerName,
  MAX(dateOfGrandSlam) mostRecentGrandSlam
FROM grandSlams
GROUP BY playerName
HAVING MAX(CASE home WHEN 'true' THEN dateOfGrandSlam END) = MAX(dateOfGrandSlam)
```

2) Use that query to filter the original table to just the rows you want:

```
SELECT a.playerName, a.dateOfGrandSlam, a.distance, a.home
FROM grandSlams a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    playerName,
    MAX(dateOfGrandSlam) mostRecentGrandSlam
  FROM grandSlams
  GROUP BY playerName
  HAVING MAX(CASE home WHEN 'true' THEN dateOfGrandSlam END) = MAX(dateOfGrandSlam)
) b ON (a.playerName = b.playerName AND a.dateOfGrandSlam = b.mostRecentGrandSlam)
```

Comment: The OPs code cleanly inserts into [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a381e/1), please check your answer before posting it.

Comment: It does, once you added the `group by`. And yeah, never known you could use `CASE` in that context. Really wondrous.

Comment: @mabi: If you like the CASE statement, consider this untangled form: `CASE WHEN home THEN dateOfGrandSlam END`. Postgres (unlike some other RDBMS) supports a proper `boolean` type, that can be used accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The basic query would be *simplest and fastest* with **`DISTINCT ON`**, which is a *Postgres specific* extension of the SQL standard `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (playername)
       playername, dateofgrandslam, distance, home 
FROM   grandslams 
GROUP  BY playername, dateofgrandslamDESC;
```

Compare performance with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html). Detailed explanation in this related answer:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Use a subquery to eliminate cases with the most recent grandslam not at home:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (playername)
           playername, dateofgrandslam, distance, home 
    FROM   grandslams 
    GROUP  BY playername, dateofgrandslam DESC
   ) sub
WHERE  home;
```

Another hot contender for the performance crown (depending on what you need exactly), and purely *standard SQL*: a [**`NOT EXISTS`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) anti-semi-join. Also simpler than it sounds:

```
SELECT playername, dateofgrandslam, distance, home 
FROM   grandslams g
WHERE  home
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   grandslams g1
   WHERE  g1.playername = g.playername
   AND    g1.dateofgrandslam > g.dateofgrandslam
   );
```

Aside: Using the lower case for `dateofgrandslam`, since unquoted identifiers are cast to lower case anyway in Postgres.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

SELECT playerName, MAX(date), distance, home
FROM grandslams 
GROUP BY playerName, distance, home
WHERE home='true'

you may need to use " or ' depending on what type of SQL you are using.

However, I am a little confused by your question due to this:

"I want to get a list of players whose most recent grandslam was at home. If their most recent grandslam wasn't at home, I don't want them to show up on my list."
and then
"This is not what I want - I want ONLY the most recent home grandslams IF there were no away grandslams more recently."

Are you looking for the most recent grandslam in general? or just the most recent home grandslam?

Comment: I'm looking for the most recent home grandslam but only if there were no even more recent away grandslams.

Comment: I noticed I had missed the "home" in the group by, but other then that no I did not try it as I'm not going to attempt to create those tables for the purpose of testing a query